# wxWigets rounded frame has black background

Tags: c++, user-interface, wxwidgets

I am trying to make a wxWidgets application and I am using i3 on Arch Linux.

After getting it setup I am noticing that the rounded corners (added by my i3 configuration), have a black background under them. What should I do to remove the black background and make it transparent?

My wxWidgets application main.cpp:

```cpp
#include <wx/wxprec.h>
#ifndef WX_PRECOMP
#include <wx/wx.h>
#endif

class ToolsApp : public wxApp
{
public:
    virtual bool OnInit();
};
class ToolsFrame : public wxFrame
{
public:
    ToolsFrame(const wxString &title, const wxPoint &pos, const wxSize &size);

private:
    void OnExit(wxCommandEvent &event);
    void OnAbout(wxCommandEvent &event);
    void OnSupport(wxCommandEvent &event);
    wxDECLARE_EVENT_TABLE();
};
enum
{
    ID_SUPPORT = 1
};
wxBEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(ToolsFrame, wxFrame)
    EVT_MENU(wxID_EXIT, ToolsFrame::OnExit)
        EVT_MENU(wxID_ABOUT, ToolsFrame::OnAbout)
            EVT_MENU(ID_SUPPORT, ToolsFrame::OnSupport)    
                wxEND_EVENT_TABLE()
                    wxIMPLEMENT_APP(ToolsApp);
bool ToolsApp::OnInit()
{
    ToolsFrame *frame = new ToolsFrame("Hello World", wxPoint(50, 50), wxSize(450, 340));
    frame->Show(true);
    return true;
}
ToolsFrame::ToolsFrame(const wxString &title, const wxPoint &pos, const wxSize &size)
    : wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, title, pos, size)
{
    wxMenu *menuHelp = new wxMenu;
    menuHelp->Append(wxID_ABOUT);
    menuHelp->Append(ID_SUPPORT, "&Support");
    wxMenuBar *menuBar = new wxMenuBar;
    menuBar->Append(menuHelp, "&Help");
    SetMenuBar(menuBar);
    CreateStatusBar();
    SetStatusText("");
}
void ToolsFrame::OnSupport(wxCommandEvent &event)
{
    std::string url = "https://example.com/";
#ifdef __UNIX__
    std::string op = std::string("xdg-open ").append(url);
#else
    std::string op = std::string("start ").append(url);
#endif
    system(op.c_str());
}
void ToolsFrame::OnExit(wxCommandEvent &event)
{
    Close(true);
}
void ToolsFrame::OnAbout(wxCommandEvent &event)
{
    wxMessageBox("...",
                 "About ...", wxOK | wxICON_INFORMATION);
}
```

screenshot of what I'm seeing:[image: Screenshot]

Edit: Add screenshot of what I see

Edit 2: Moved the screenshot to allow for further edits. Also the screenshot will not match fully to the above code as I have added some things.

Comment: can you post a screenshot of what you are looking at? Also - which port do you use? And did you build the library yourself or installed it from some kind of repository?

Comment: I will add a screenshot to the question. Yes I built wxWidgets using a CMakeLists.txt to pull it from the repo and build it. What do you mean by which port?

Comment: are you on Windows, Linux or Mac?

Comment: Take a look at [SetBackgroundStyle()](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_window.html#af14f8fd2ed2d30a9bbb5d4f9fd6594ec). You may use it for the frame, but perhaps not for its client area

Comment: I have tested using SetBackgroundStyle and cannot find a way to actually get it to remove the black background underneath. I am a bit new to using wxWidgets so I have probably missed something, could you point me to an example of doing what you said?